# Capturing and Logging MySQLI Errors in PHP within Try-Catch Blocks

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, mysqli, try-catch

I made a error log for collecting errors. I'm trying to catch all the errors in my log file but it won't collect any errors. I tried making an error on purpose to see if it does work but I checked the log file no error output. I checked my log message works fine.

```
errorLogMessage($Filename.' was executed: '. 'Lorem Ipsum');
```

```
[2023-12-12 10:28:34] [ERROR] Terms_And_Condition_Display.php was executed: Lorem Ipsum
```

I'm using mysqli

```
catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
{
    errorLogMessage($Filename.' was executed: '. $e->getMessage());
}
```

Entire try catch:

```
try
{
    $sql = "SELECT tac.Use_Agreement, tac.Privacy_Policy, tac.Age_Requirement, tac.Dispute_Resolution,
                   tac.Indemnification, tac.Liability_Limitation, tac.Pet_Appointment_Guidelines
            FROM terms_and_condition tac";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $UseAgreement = htmlspecialchars($row['Use_Agreement']);
        $PrivacyPolicy = htmlspecialchars($row['Privacy_Policy']);
        $AgeRequirement = htmlspecialchars($row['Age_Requirement']);
        $Disputeresolution = htmlspecialchars($row['Dispute_Resolution']);
        $Indemnification = htmlspecialchars($row['Indemnification']);
        $LiabilityLimitation = htmlspecialchars($row['Liability_Limitation']);
        $PetAppointmentGuidelines = htmlspecialchars($row['Pet_Appointment_Guidelines']);
        echo
        '
            '.$UseAgreement.'
        ';
    }
    else
    {
        errorLogMessage($Filename.' was executed: '. 'No data were found.');
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    errorLogMessage($Filename.' was executed: '. $e->getMessage());
}
```

I also tried using exception but none of them worked.

```
catch(PDOException $e)
```

```
catch (Exception $e)
```

It did kinda work when I added this but my echo stopped working.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

Comment: `I'm using mysqli` ...well then, self-evidently `PDOException` was never going to be useful. `PDO != mysqli`

Comment: Anyway if you enble mysqli error reporting (via that `mysqli_report` command) then you don't _need_ to catch and log errors manually - the errors will be reported to PHP, and then you can configure PHP to automatically log all errors, including the SQL ones. Read https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#error_handling and then https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting to learn a robust and sane way to deal with errors in mysqli and PHP

Comment: I assume you are not on PHP 8.1 yet.

Comment: You say you want to catch all errors, so why do you have a catch around a single function. Why not just employ a global error handler for ALL PHP errors. There's nothing special about mysqli errors that you would have to catch them.